# Is it really wrong to eat immediately after a weight loss workout?

Tags: weight-loss, workout, nutrition

I heard that eating after weight loss workout will reduce the effect of losing weight. I heard I should wait for at least 2-3 hours before eating anything or body won't consume fat or something like that.

Is there anyway this could be true?

Comment: What is a "weight loss" workout?  And, where did you get this "information"?

Comment: @rrirower I meant the exercises that you perform in order to burn fat. I really don't remember a specific source. I read it somewhere and I heard some people say it (including athlete trainers). That's why I'm asking here.

Comment: Any exercise has the potential for assisting with weight loss if combined with a sensible eating plan.  What you heard sounds like a myth to me.  I'd run from those trainers.

Answer (score 1):

You save energy in form of glycogen, because it's the fastest way of storing and using energy. When you workout u lose a lot of this energy and you start taking energy from other resources like fat. That only happens if you already lost your fast way of getting energy. When your glycogen is restored with a big meal after training you stop using fat for energy but start to use the new and easy carbohydrates. Please don't take this as an advise to not eat after your workout. I think it's really important to eat after your workout because your body needs minerals and proteins. If you want to lose weight just eat well and you won't have any problem with eating after training.

Answer (score 0):

Good Morning Sir,

What you've heard has some true reasoning on it, but you can eat if you're starving because if not, you'll also hit your brain's performance.

What you should really care about is the energy deficit:
Our body just consistently consums fat to produce energy & therefore make our body work in a good way.
You should just pull apart any FAT rich meals & high energy plates so that our body will be forced to take that energy from your already stored FAT (the one you wanna get rid of).

That's the whole idea. Just set meals that are based on this simple trick and everything will go according to your plans.

Have a good day and a great workout.

Answer (score 0):

Two quick things. First off, there is a danger in eating after your workout in that your body will be demanding caloric intake and humans are bad at estimating just how much energy they burned. Go ahead and eat, but be aware of and log your calories to prevent yourself from taking in calories in excess of what you burned.

Secondly, if you're doing any sort of weight-training, the current recommendation seems to be to eat some protein right afterwards. It will be used pretty rapidly to build the muscles back up plus protein is relatively filling for its calories, so you're less likely to overeat.